# R - VScode issues

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I've been using R in VScode for quite sometime without issue until I migrated computers.

Intellisense does not work anymore even though I followed the same installation steps on both computers. Whenever I try to run R code this error pops up.

```
VSCode R Session Watcher requires jsonlite, rlang. Please install manually in order to use VSCode-R.
```

This used to work on a Windows 10 laptop, and is not working on my current windows 11 laptop.

If anyone knows how I can fix this please let me know!

Comment: The error message tells you to install `jsonlite` and `rlang` manually in order to use VSCode-R. Did you try to install them manually/